# getting 'background' property as undefined in 'theme.palette' in MUI Styled Badge

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As a begineer in react, with working in a project found out some issue with it !

Here is my react script,

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import './HeaderAppMenuLogged.css';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { Badge, IconButton, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import Home from '@material-ui/icons/Home'
import { HomeOutlined, Notifications } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { NotificationsNoneOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import AccountCircleOutlined from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircleOutlined';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

const StyledBadge = styled(Badge)(({ theme }) => ({
    
    '& .MuiBadge-badge': {
        right: 2,
        top: 4,
        border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.background.paper}`,
        padding: '0 4px',
    },
}));

const StyledHomeBadge = styled(Badge)(({ theme }) => ({
    '& .MuiBadge-badge':{
        right:4,
        top:2.5,
        border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.background.paper}`,
        padding: '0 4px',
    }
}));

function HeaderAppMenuLogged({current_state}) {
    return (
        <div className="header__menu">
            <Tooltip title="Home">
                <IconButton
                    size="large"
                    edge="start"
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="open drawer"
                    sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                >
                    {/* <MenuIcon className="menu__icon" /> */}
                    {current_state === "home"?
                        <Home /> :
                        <StyledHomeBadge color="primary" variant="dot" invisible={false}>
                            <HomeOutlined />
                        </StyledHomeBadge>   
                    }

                </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Tooltip title="notifications">
                <IconButton
                    size="large"
                    edge="start"
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="open drawer"
                    sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                >
                        {current_state === "notifications" ? 
                        <Notifications /> : 
                        <StyledBadge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                            <NotificationsNoneOutlined />
                        </StyledBadge>
                        }
                </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
       <Tooltip title="profile">
           <IconButton
               size="large"
               edge="start"
               color="inherit"
               aria-label="open drawer"
               sx={{ mr: 2 }}
           >
               {current_state === "profile" ? <AccountCircle /> : <AccountCircleOutlined />}

               {/* <NotificationsIcon /> */}
           </IconButton>
       </Tooltip>
   </div>
    )
}

export default HeaderAppMenuLogged
```

and while compiling i am getting error like,

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'background')
(anonymous function)
src/HeaderAppMenuLogged.js:17
  14 |     '& .MuiBadge-badge': {
  15 |         right: 2,
  16 |         top: 4,
> 17 |         border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.background.paper}`,
  18 |         padding: '0 4px',
  19 |     },
  20 | }));
```

I actually just take refrence directly from https://mui.com/components/badges/
At the end i cant get some free space between icon and badge in result and need help with it!

Comment: Can you post how you used `ThemeProvider` and passed the `theme` props? https://v4.mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider

Comment: @hotcakedev I don't think there is any problem in code as I take code directly from mui site, is this problem with some installation or doesn't work in ubuntu? EDIT: however same code works fine on windows OS